# Calling macro with Application.Run gives an error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I can't find the cause of the error 1004 returned by the Application.Run command.

```
Sub Called()
  MsgBox "Yes"
End Sub

Sub Caller()
  Call Called ' works
  subName = "Called"
  Application.Run Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & subName ' error 1004
End Sub
```

Error description (in French):

```
---------------------------
Erreur d'exécution '1004':
Erreur définie par l'application ou par l'objet
---------------------------
```

Every solution I found after googling this issue leads to the same error. The Caller and Called subs are in the same "Sheet1" module.

I'm a bit lost. I wonder if the issue is related to XL security? Or something missing in References?

Comment: I'm using XL 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your code out of the Sheet1 module and into a normal module.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is not the cause. I tried the quotation, same result,. And I moved the file to "c:\temp\toto.xlsm", same result.

Comment: @JnLlnd Doh!!  I hadn't noticed that you said that your code was inside a Sheet.  Move the code into a project Module and it should be fine.  (But you will still need to be careful about spaces, etc, in filenames once it is working.)  Actually `Application.Run "Sheet1." & subName` should also work, even when it is in the `Sheet1` code module.

Comment: You are correct. I know it was a dummy error... I was under the impression that Sheet - Regular. Thank you @YowE3K.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by moving the second macro to the same module.

Looks like a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remark: I had the Problem with Error 1004 "sub or function not found" error after Application.Run macro, arg

But macro without arg worked.

I found that in the target Workbook the way of declaration of the parameter arg caused a difference:

macro(arg$) -> caused error

macro(arg As String) -> worked (for a moment)

Later same errors again ...
Very strange behaviour of Excel VBA Editor: In the line with the Application.Run command VBE had a offset of 2 characters from the cursor, which means when I set the cursor after the n of Run and pressed backspace the R of Run was deleted. Same offset when I typed characters.
That issue was moving when I copy-paste that line.

I found out that the errors occured in the lines which had that issue.

I solved it by typing the line new (regarding that the new line didn't have that issue) and deleting the old line, which had that issue.